# Show NavigationView in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Coming from `UIKit`, I was just trying `SwiftUI`.

I just wanted to show hello world in a view with navigation bar. So I wrote below code.

I can see `Text` widget but I can't see `NavigationView` widget.

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text("Hello World")
      }
    }
    .navigationBarTitle(Text("ForgotPassword")
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .fontWeight(.medium), displayMode: .inline)
    .shadow(color: Color.blue, radius: 0, x: 0, y: 5)
    .navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
    .background(Color.red)
  }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
          Text("Hello World")
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("ForgotPassword")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.medium), displayMode: .inline)
        .shadow(color: Color.blue, radius: 0, x: 0, y: 5)
        .navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
      }
    }
```

Comment: `.navigationBarTitle(Text("ForgotPassword")` should be on `NavigationView`. Right?

Comment: It should be inside the `NavigationView`

Comment: The navigation options are specified on the outer container inside the NavigationView. In this case the VStack